# Plesk VPS Server - Email Forwarding

Tags: email, html-email, vps, plesk, forwarding

My server's Plesk panel as been upgraded to 10.4.4, and since this change I have noticed small annoying changes with regards to email forwarding.

Previously, the email accounts forwarded the emails to an external email provider (Such as Google Mail) and retained the HTML format of the emails. But now it is just displaying the emails as pure text. Such as:

```
Content-Type: text/plain; charset="ISO-8859-1"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable
```

And the content afterwards, but has text, no images etc.

Is their a setting or something so that it will forward as HTML and not plain text? i have tried with a few external emails such as Google, Hotmail, and ISP email accounts.

Answer (score 0):

This must be some sort of webmail settings.

If you use Horde you can try playing with Options > Mail > Message replies / forwards > 
[x] When replying/forwarding to a message, should we use the same format as the original message